# How to Install Logisim on Ubuntu (version Ubuntu 20.04 )

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

Logisim is a logic simulator which permits circuits to be designed and simulated using a graphical user interface. Released under the GNU Public License, Logisim is a free software designed to run on the Windows, macOS, and Linux operating systems. Its code is Java using the Swing graphical user interface library.

Comment: The Download page has clear instructions. Did you read it? Is there some element that you didn't understand? Did it not work? Was there an error message?

Comment: It specifically mentioned Windows and Mac OS, but it doesn't mention Linux at all (at least the download page my study program provided me with), so I think that its a pretty legit question to be honest

Answer (score 1):

Logisim runs on JDK/Java run time environment. Logisim should run on any platform supporting Java, version 5 or later. Logisim requires Java 5 or later.

Just follow these steps:
So firstly install Java by using these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install default-jdk
```

Then check your java version:

```
java -version
```

Output :

```
openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

[image: Terminal screenshot]

Then download Logisim from whatever you want.
Again follow these steps -

1. Right-click on **Logisim Jar** file.
2. You will see "Open With OpenJDK Java 11 Runtime". Click on it.
3. Logisim will run.